# Find out the most contributing variables/features of an R H2O AutoML model?

Tags: r, variables, h2o

I'm currently working with some insurance data to predict in what kind of insured sum class a customer will fall. To achieve this I'm using the AutoML function of the H2O package in R. Now that I have my model I'd like to be able to see which variables/features in my data contribute the most to the predictions the model makes. Is such a thing possible with H2O? If not, what would be another good option to achieve this with R? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely possible. If the best fitting model that AutoML has selected is not an ensemble then you can use the following to plot the variable importances (where model is your `model` extracted from AutoML),

```
library(h2o)
h2o.varimp_plot(model)
```

If the best fitting model is an ensemble then things are a little more complicated. A good option is to use the [lime](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lime/index.html) package to look at local importance.

```
 library(h2o)
 library(lime)

 ## Train explainer
 explainer <- lime(train, model)

 ## Get explanations for a subset of samples
 explanation <- explain(train[1:5, ], explainer, n_features = 10)

 ## Plot global explanations
 plot_explanations(explanation)

 ## Plot local explanations
 plot_features(explanation)
```

Comment: My two best performing models are indeed ensembles, but I'm gonna try this out for my other models.

Gonna check out lime for my ensembles, thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is new since the answer was posted, but with H2O AutoML in R I get a warning message "In h2o.varimp(model) : No variable importances for H2OAutoML"

Comment: Are you running that on the model object or the automl object? Needs to be on the model object.